# 19.10 Hibernation resume black screen (AMD Vega 8)

Tags: drivers, grub2, hibernate, 19.10

Upon resuming from hibernation (pm-hibernate) on Wayland desktop, there is a black screen. Everything else works and I can SSH into the computer just fine.
In order to fix this I can set nomodeset on /etc/default/grub and running update-grub, however this breaks other things and causes poor performance.

However, if I enable nomodeset and update grub, then hibernate, then resume, everything works and the performance still works as if nomodeset is not active (possibly due to the computer not being rebooted and just hibernated/resumed). Enabling and disabling nomodeset is obviously not ideal every time I wish to reboot and even using a script to do so is not exactly a clean solution.

Any ideas on troubleshooting/resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

amdgpu is up to date as well. Ryzen 5 3500U with Vega 8 is the APU.

```
Linux ****** 5.3.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 09:22:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using systemctl hibernate instead pm-hibernate.
I had a lot of issues like this using pm-utils until I realized I could use systemctl.
Maybe this will not solve your problem but is worth trying.